# Depth of list in scheme

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, racket

I'm trying to write a program in scheme that will find the maximum depth of a list. My code so far is:

---

```
(define (depth l)
  (define (helper l count)
    ( cond
        ((null? l) count)
        ((not(list? (car l))) (helper (cdr l) count))
        (else (helper (car l) (+ count 1)) )
    )
  )
  (helper l 1)
)
```

It works for lists of this type `(depth '(1 2 3 (2))) -> 2`, but obviously not for list of the type `(depth '( (2) ((3))) -> 3`. The problem is that when I first encounter a list, I automatically jump to it increment the count and call it recursively again, ignoring the other elements of the list. I want to fix this problem and I thought of adding another variable `temp` which to hold the current count for each element in the list and check if it is bigger than `count` and if it is true I `set!` `count` to `temp`, but again I have a problem with the recursion. My other idea was to use another list in which to `append` `count` on every step and find the maximum value in that list, but I couldn't realize that too. Any ideas how to do this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an implementation using `map`:

```
(define (max-depth l)
  (define (helper depth el)
    (cond
      [(null? el) (add1 depth)]
      [(list? el)
       (apply max
               (map (curry helper (add1 depth))
                    el))]
      [else depth]))
  (helper 0 l))
```

While I think this implementation is fairly elegant, it admittedly is not tail-recursive.

Here is a slightly more complex, breadth-first tail-recursive implementation:

```
(define (max-depth l)
  (define (helper depth els)
    (define remaining (filter list? els))
    (if (zero? (length remaining))
        depth
        (helper (add1 depth) (apply append remaining))))
  (helper 1 l))
```